# Can I use JTAG Boundary Scan if SRST is not available

Tags: jtag, reset

I am attempting to integrate JTAG Boundary Scan onto an existing ARM9 board using SAM-ICE as the JTAG Emulator.

One unfortunate oversight is that CPU/System Reset (`nRST` or aka `nSRST` ) was not brought out onto the header on this board. However, JTAG `nTRST` is exposed.

Would I still be able to execute JTAG Boundary Scan without access to system reset pin? The documentation on this is not clear, as both reset pins are technically "optional".